# Salesforce Flow for Creating Multiple Records Based on Multiple Field Updates

Tags: visual-workflow

We recently uncovered a limitation of the out of the box history tracking in Salesforce on Accounts, that it does not stamp the id of the record change when it is a lookup/master detail relationship field, only the text.

We are trying to solve this by creating a new custom object called BizDW History Tracking and a flow that creates records on this object when fields on Accounts are updated.

I tried to use a decision flow to create records based on field changes. However, it will not work if multiple fields are updated at once. For example if a custom lookup field called Ownership Group And thee Parent Account are updated at the same time, it only creates one record.

I know I can create individual flows, but I'd like to keep it consolidated to 1 if possible.

Does anyone know how I can solve this to create multiple records on the BizDW History Tracking object when both fields are updated at the same time?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you rethink this

Your initial assertion is not correct -- there are two history records written, one showing the ID change, one showing the Name change. Only the latter is displayed but both are in the database

Here's an example using this query from my dev edition of a change in Case.ContactId

```
SELECT Id, CreatedDate,  Field, OldValue, NewValue from CaseHistory 
 WHERE CaseId = '5000xxxxxxxxxxx'
```

[image]

If this information needs to be displayed, you can create a VF or LWC or even Screen Flow w/ DataTable to show this information that already exists in the database